# IndexError: string index out of range <making encrypt, decrypt program>

Tags: python

```
import random
#get filename
name = input('Enter filename: ')

#load file
try:
    input_file = open(name, 'r')
except IOError:
    print('File does not exist. Program will terminate.')

#make key value
line = input_file.readline()

key = []
key_mix = []

for i in range(len(line)):
    if line[i] not in key:
        key.append(line[i])
for i in range(len(line)):
    if line[i] not in key_mix:
        key_mix.append(line[i])

random.shuffle(key_mix)


#encryption
if name.split('.')[1] == 'txt':
    try:
        key_file = open(name.split('.')[0] + '.key', 'w')
        enc_file = open(name.split('.')[0] + '.enc', 'w')
    except IOError:
        print('File does not exist. Program will terminate.')

    key_write = ['']
    for g in range(len(key)):
        key_write[0] += key_mix[g]

    for i in range(len(key)):
        keys = str(key[i]) + ',' + str(key_mix[i])
        key_file.write(keys+'\n')

    couple = {}

    for k in range(len(key)):
        couple[key[k]] = key_mix[k]


    enc = ['']

    for t in range(len(line)):
        enc[0] += couple.get(line[t])

    enc_file.write(enc[0])
    input_file.close()
    key_file.close()
    enc_file.close()

#decryption
elif name.split('.')[1] == 'enc':
    try:
        key_file = open(name.split('.')[0] + '.key', 'r')
        dec_file = open(name.split('.')[0] + '.txt', 'w')
    except IOError:
        print('File does not exist. Program will terminate.')
    line = input_file.readline()

    dec = ['']
    sol = {}
    while True:
        sen = key_file.readline()
        if not sen: break
        sol.update({sen[2]:sen[0]})*Problem Here*

    for m in range(len(line)):
        dec[0] += sol.get(line[m])


    dec_file.write(dec[0])
    input_file.close()
    key_file.close()
    dec_file.close()
```

It makes error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

and when I check my `.key` file, it comes like

```
t,o
h,l
e,s
r,h
i,t
s,r
 ,n
n,v
o,u
u,e
f,i
l,f
v,
```

but when I print readline, it comes like

```
t,o
(blank)
e,s
(blank)
i,t
(blank)
,n
(blank)
o,u
(blank)
f,i
(blank)
v, 
(blank)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Start by printing `sen` to understand where it goes wrong. You are trying to access the 3rd character of a string that has fewer than 3...

Comment: @JulienBernu because the sen looks like s,g
it has 3 character
I wonder why key_file.readline()'s result has omission